# C# search a list

Tags: c#, list

Alright, ive created a code for a library, its rather simple but I need to search by keyword to find a title of a book.  Ive created a Books list, with strings Title, Author, ISBN, and Genre.  I just need someone to point me in the right direction for what to search for :)  Ill attach the partial code just to show you the list ive created! I just need to know what to put in my method Search. Thank You

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

 namespace CodersVilleLibrary
{
public class Books
{
    public static List<Books> _books = new List<Books>();



    public string Title
    { get; set; }



    public string Author
    { get; set; }



    public string ISBN
    { get; set; }

    public string Genre
     { get; set; }

    static Books()
    {
        _books.Add(new Books()
        {
            Title = "Lord of the Rings",
            Author = "J.R.R. Tolkein",
            ISBN = "0395595118",
            Genre = "Adventure"
        });
        _books.Add(new Books()
        {
            Title = "Lord of the Flies",
            Author = "William Golding",
            ISBN = "0571056865",
            Genre = "Sci-Fi"
        });

        _books.Add(new Books()
        {
            Title = "Hunger Games",
            Author = "Suzanne Collins",
            ISBN = "9780439023528",
            Genre = "Sci-Fi"
        });




    }









    }

    }
```

Users Class

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

  namespace CodersVilleLibrary
 {
    public class Users
   {

    private static List<Users> _users = new List<Users>();


    public string Username
    { get; set; }

    public string Password
      { get; set; }

    public Address Address
      { get; set; }

    public static Users Authorize()
    {
        string username = null;
        string password = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Username: ");
        username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Password: ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();


        return _users.Where(u => u.Username == username && u.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();

    }



    static Users()
    {
        _users.Add(new Users()
        {
            Username = "FDalton",
            Password = "Kelton",
            Address = new Address
            {
                City = "Mascoutah",
                State = "IL",
                StreetAddress1 = " 834 Locust Dr.",
                ZIP = "62258"
            }
        });

        _users.Add(new Users()
        {
            Username = "Bnotz",
            Password = "Ben",
            Address = new Address
            {
                City = "O'Fallon",
                State = "IL",
                StreetAddress1 = "700 Old School Road",
                ZIP = "62269"
            }
        });




        }

    internal void CreateSession()
    {
        int selection = GetAction();
        if (selection != 3)
        {
            Books bks = SearchBooks();

            switch (selection)
            {

                // Search
                case 1:

                    break;

                // ViewAll
                case 2:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }


       private Books SearchBooks()
        {

var byTitle = Books.Where(while


           } 





    int GetAction()
    {

        int choice = -1;
        bool isValid = true;
        string input = null;

        do
        {
            if(!isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! Try Again.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Codesville Library System");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select an action");
            Console.WriteLine("___________________________");
            Console.WriteLine(" 1.) Search for a Book");
            Console.WriteLine(" 2.) See all books in the system");
            Console.WriteLine(" 3.) Exit");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            input = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        while ((!(isValid = Int32.TryParse(input, out choice))) ||
            choice < 1 ||
            choice > 3);
        return choice;



    }


    }

      }
```

Comment: you said you want to search by title  ? in the right direction for what to search for  ?

Comment: Where's is your Search Method?

Comment: Seems like your class should be `Book` not `Books` and `_books` doesn't belong to that class. (BTW: a public field like `_books` is not a c# way)

Comment: I didn't put the whole code up, my Search method was in my Users class.  but I will add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to query the list.

To find all `sci-fi` books:

```
var sciFiBooks = _books.Where(w => w.Genre.Equals("sci-fi",                     
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Or, as asked, to find by title (using a keyword):

```
var byTitle = _books.Where(w => w.Title.Contains("search_term").ToList();
```

Comment: Thank You! that's all I wanted to know! :)

Comment: @GabrielleSchweiss : Please remember to mark the post that solved your problem as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Your code seems to make no difference between your individual book object and its data structure. What I would advise doing just to make working with the code a little easier (and you have this partially done already, too!):

1. Make a class called `Book` that's simply a single book at holds the title, ISBN, author, and genre.
2. Keep your books class as is, holding multiple books, and then write search methods:

   - `SearchName(string name)`
   - `SearchGenre(string genre)`
   - `SearchISBN(string isbn)` or maybe an int isbn, too.
   - `SearchGenre(string name)`
   - and a `SearchAll(string search)` that uses search on the other methods.

This way, you can keep your classes organized and make searching easier with these four methods. For the actual code, you can probably use something like this for each method.

```
foreach (Book b in _books) {

 if (b.Name.Equals(search))
  return b;

}
```

Comment: okay, so I did the class called book that holds like public string Title {get; set; } etc...  then a book class book that holds like _books.add(new Book() {Titile = "Lord of the rings", Author = J.R Tolkien", etc.... then I made search with the foreach so how do I get user input in there for a case?

Comment: Just have a class called Main, or whatever name you like, and from there you can instantiate your Books object, add several Book objects to it, and then call the methods (you can pass parameters that you get from the console user):